# How to fix "Error: No module named mysql.connector"

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-connector

I am working with some python program where I need to import `mysql.connector`. But I am facing `ImportError: No module named connector`. I already read answers on same issue and also explore google to find out and try some step to fix still it not fixed.

I am working on MacOS. and I guess by default python 2.7.18 is installed and also I installed python 3.8.9.

So I came to know that I have to install `pip install mysql-connector` for python 2.X but when I ran this in my terminal it is showing **command not found: pip** . Then I tried to install **`pip3 install mysql-connector`**. for python3 and it got successfully installed.

But Still problem not fixed. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Exactly how did you install Python 3?    It's possible your `pip3` is for the system Python3, and you're trying to use homebrew's Python 3.  Try doing `python3 -m pip install mysql-connector`.

Comment: Well I am using VS Code from there I installed Python(Pylance). Moreover I already tried it  'python3 -m pip install mysql-connector'. Still same error

Comment: The root problem is that you have multiple installations of Python, and you're not getting the right one.  VSCode can either use your system Python or install its own.  Have you run the installer in the VSCode terminal?

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I found what the error is when i run in VS code terminal all things gone right in python 3 it also import mysql.connector but when i do with python2 it showing error. So i guess i did opt correct path variable for Interpreter

Answer (score 1):

It could be the case where you are running the Python file with the wrong Python installation. In VS Code we can choose the interpreter using which we want to run our Python file.

> By default, the Python extension looks for and uses the first Python
> interpreter it finds in the system path. To select a specific
> environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the
> Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Just choose Python 3.8.9 from the list of interpreters. For complete guide you can refer to the documentation:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Answer (score 0):

You got two Python installed in your system. Python3 and Python2.
Pip3 is just for python3.
You must use pip2 or pip2.7 for work with python2.
Search if you got the pip2 package installed is not then install it.

Answer (score -1):

Before importing `mysql.connector` in your code, install `mysql-connector-python` package using `pip` package installer. The total command may be as follows:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```